# Trade offs between view and viewsets

Tags: django-rest-framework

I don't know why the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#trade-offs-between-views-vs-viewsets) says:

> That doesn't mean it's always the right approach to take. There's a similar set of trade-offs to consider as when using class-based views instead of function based views. Using viewsets is less explicit than building your views individually.

If I want to make a REST API (like in ruby-on-rail) I think `viewsets` is a good approach to take.

Can anyone explain more about it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The main advantage of using `viewsets` over `views` is brevity. In the simple case, you can get more done with fewer lines of code.

The main disadvantage is that the simplifying assumptions made by `viewsets` might not always fit the problem space you are working in. As with class-based views in Django, if you try to apply the wrong pattern to a problem you can end up doing more work than you need to solve a problem.

My personal heuristic is that if I am doing the full set of CRUD operations on a model, I start with `viewsets` and go from there until I feel the convenience they provide is no longer worth the trouble I am incurring in that specific instance; if I am working with an API endpoint that doesn't map to any models, I'm far more likely to just use a `view`.

If I had the following models:

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Gizmo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False)
    last_dusted = models.DateField(null=True)

class Sprocket(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False)
    last_dusted = models.DateField(null=True)
```

And I wanted to support the standard HTTP methods with their normal meanings, (namely GET and POST on the list view and GET, PUT, and DELETE on the detail view), I'd create a `GizmoViewSet`, a `SprocketViewSet` and call it a day.

Say I also wanted to offer API consumers the ability to dust off all of the gizmos at once. In that case, it would make sense to add a `dust` method to the `GizmoViewSet` using the `@list_route` decorator. Suppose that what I really wanted to do though was to offer a single endpoint where that API consumer could dust all the `Gizmo`s and the `Sprocket`s off at once. That doesn't really map very well to either viewset, so I'd add a one off view:

```
import datetime

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from my_app.models import Gizmo, Sprocket

# I used a function-based API view here, but a CBV APIView
# would work just as well. Matter of personal preference...
@api_view
def dust_everything(request):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    Gizmo.objects.all().update(last_dusted=today)
    Sprocket.objects.all().update(last_dusted=today)
    return Response({"status_of_dusting": "successful"})
```

So in that case I wouldn't be tearing out all my viewsets and replacing them with views; I'm adding an extra view to supplement the existing viewsets where it makes sense.