# Difference between views and viewsets?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Maybe relevant:  [What does django rest framework mean trade offs between view vs viewsets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32430689/11573842)

What is the difference between `views` and `viewsets`? And what about `router` and `urlpatterns`?

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial about viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)? It describes moving from views + urlpatterns to viewsets + routers. Is there anything specific that you don't understand?

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, yes, I read the tutorial and while it explains very well how to work with viewsets it doesn't seem to spend many words on what are the differences between viewsets and views. The only paragraph that seems relevant is "ViewSet classes are almost the same thing as View classes, except that they provide operations such as read, or update, and not method handlers such as get or put". But even this paragraph doesn't seem particular clear (e.g., why would you prefer read and update to get or put?).

Comment: The benefit of `read` and `update` over `get` and `put` is that you have uncoupled the api methods from the HTTP methods used to call them. You can then use routers to hook the viewset into the urls, which saves code and can make your API more consistent.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`ViewSets` and `Routers` are simple tools to speed up the implementation of your API if you're aiming for standard behaviour and standard URLs.

Using `ViewSet` you don't have to create separate views for getting a list of objects and detail of one object. `ViewSet` will handle for you in a consistent way both list and detail.

Using `Router` will connect your `ViewSet` into "standarized" (it's not standard in any global way, just some structure that was implemented by creators of Django REST framework) structure of URLs. That way you don't have to create your `urlpatterns` by hand and you're guaranteed that all of your URLs are consistent (at least on the layer that `Router` is responsible for).

It looks like not much, but when implementing some huge API where you will have many and many `urlpatterns` and views, using `ViewSets` and `Routers` will make big difference.

For better explanation: this is code using `ViewSets` and `Routers`:

`views.py`:

```
from snippets.models import Article
from rest_framework import viewsets
from yourapp.serializers import ArticleSerializer

class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from yourapp import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'articles', views.ArticleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And equivalent result using normal `Views` and no `routers`:

`views.py`:

```
from snippets.models import Article
from snippets.serializers import ArticleSerializer
from rest_framework import generics


class ArticleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer


class ArticleDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from yourapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'articles/^', views.ArticleList.as_view(), name="article-list"),
    url(r'articles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/^', views.ArticleDetail.as_view(), name="article-detail"),
]
```

Comment: Sorry, but I continue not to see it. :( What is the difference between: `router = routers.SimpleRouter(); router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)` and `urlpatterns = [url(r'^accounts/', AccountView),]`?

Comment: First one will register 2 URLs, one for list and one for detail, see updated answer

Comment: Great example this helped me a lot, even though I've used class based views I had I hard time seeing the difference. This makes it so obvious, I wish the docs were like this. Quick question though: In your first example for the viewsets did you forgot to import `Article`?